# Symfony2 Doctrine2 trouble with optional one to many relation

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have a problem with Doctrine2 and two relationed entities.

There is a user-entity that can (not must) have one or a collection of social-entity referenced which contains a social network link.

I do not control Doctrine and I'm still learning relationship.

I want to add a user with/without adding social network link.

After several researches and testing, I am still unable to find a solution.

Here is my user-entity

```
<?php
//...

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="admin_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=40)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    //...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Social", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $socials;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->socials = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //Some getters setters

    /**
     * Add socials
     *
     * @param Social $socials
     * @return User
     */
    public function addSocials(Social $socials)
    {
        $this->socials[] = $socials;
        $socials->setUser($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove socials
     *
     * @param Social $socials
     */
    public function removeSocials(Social $socials)
    {
        $this->socials->removeElement($socials);
    }

    /**
     * Get socials
     *
     * @return Collection 
     */
    public function getSocials()
    {
        return $this->socials;
    }
}
```

Here is the social-entity

```
<?php

/**
 * Social
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="admin_social")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SocialRepository")
 */
class Social
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="socials", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    //getters setters

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return Social
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

The userType code looks like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('username', 'text', array(
            'attr'=> array('class' => 'span6',),
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
        )
    )

    // ....

    ->add('sociaux', 'collection', array('type'         => new SocialType(),
                                         'allow_add'    => true,
                                         'allow_delete' => true,
                                         'by_reference' => false,))
;
```

Finally the controller code :

```
public function addAction()
{
    $user = new User;
    // Create the form
    $form = $this->createForm( new UserType, $user );
    // Gets the request
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    // Checks if the request have type POST
    if ( $request->getMethod() == 'POST' ) {
        // Links the request and the form
        $form->bind( $request );
        // Checks if all input values are correct
        if ( $form->isValid() ) {
            // Save user object in database
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            // Persist entity user
            $em->persist( $user );
            $em->flush();

            //...
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

When I try to add a user without social-entity I have no error, but in the database I have in social table a row with null values. Please help.

**UPDATE**

In user-entity I added this :

```
if( !( $socials->getName() === null && $socials->getUrl() === null ) )
{
        $this->socials[] = $socials;
        $socials->setUser($this);
}
```

Now there is no row inserted in `social` table, but when I try editing the user, I have two collection field (duplicated).

See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIyyx.png)

Here my template file (Twig) :

```
    <div class="widget-body">
    {{ form_start(form, { 'action': path('acme_admin_edit_user', {'id': userId}), 'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'} }) }}
        <div class="control-group">
            {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
            {{ form_label(form.username) }}
            <div class="controls">
                {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
            </div>
        </div>     

        <!-- ... -->

        <div id="acme_adminbundle_useredittype_socials" data-prototype="{{ form_row(form.socials.vars.prototype) | escape }}">
            {% for social in form.socials %}
                <div>
                    <label class="required text-primary lead">Lien n°{{ loop.index }}</label>
                    <div id="acme_adminbundle_useredittype_socials_{{ loop.index0 }}">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            {{ form_errors(social.name) }}
                            {{ form_label(social.name) }}
                            <div class="controls">
                                {{ form_widget(social.name) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            {{ form_errors(social.url) }}
                            {{ form_label(social.url) }}
                            <div class="controls">
                                {{ form_widget(social.url) }}
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="txt-center well">
            <input type="submit" class="auto-margin btn btn-primary btn-large" />
        </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the form will always show one social and will always end up saving it.  After your $form->isValid you can check to see if the social entity has any values filled in.  If not then remove it before persisting.  Even better (though more complicated to understand) use a data transformer so this happens automatically: http://jnotes.jonasfischer.net/2013/11/symfony2-form-types-and-non-mandatory-relationships/

Comment: BTW, the cascade option should go on the user side of the entity.

Comment: @Cerad It should not include one collection subform by default, right?

Comment: @Cerad thanks for your answer. I updated my question, please have a look

Comment: In the `social` table there is no row associated with the user that I edit, but in `user-entity` when I dump the attribute `socials`, I have this user as the `owner`. Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
```

from your `User` class. `@JoinColumn` should be defined only on one side of relationship and since `Social` entity contains `name` and `referencedColumnName` it is unnecessary inside the `User`.

Comment: I tried your solution and I have no error, but in the database I have in `Social` table a row with null values and the `user_id` column contain the `id` of the user I've just add